# What governs the order of row processing in King Cashing 2?

Tags: king-cashing-2

In King Cashing 2 battles, you "spin" a slot machine per turn to determine the amount of damage to be dealt to the enemy on that turn.

I noticed that the rows are processed in different orders per turn. When more than one row is eligible to be processed, the rows are not always processed from top to bottom.

While it's not significant all of the time, when you have the Necromancer class with you that replaces a "Miss" in the weapons (2nd) reel with a human weapon, it definitely is. Sometimes the row with a newly-created human weapon is processed, sometimes it isn't.

Is there a set of rules which determines the order of row processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order is as follows:

1. Middle Line
2. Top Line
3. Bottom Line

It is based on how old slot machines work where you added coins to get more lines. The middle one was always the first one and adding just another coin gave you the top line and then the third line.